# Software Center keeps crashing

Tags: software-center, crash

Last week I typed in a command for /ect/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list into my terminal and ever since then Ubuntu Software Center Keeps crashing. 
The report says

> `<class System Error> (E:Type'<!DOCTYPE' ia not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list)`

I need help to prevent it from crashing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the problem is you've added an incompatible source or text was added to your `/ect/apt/sources.list.d/` directory. It's causing problems updating your software repo cache. Remove the added file/sources, then you should be able to update (`apt-get update`) normally.

The error sounds like there's some type of HTML on line 1 of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list` that got in there somehow; that shouldn't be there. If you know what lines or sources were added, you can use any text editor to edit the source files (`sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list` for example), or a file browser to remove the whole file if it doesn't belong there.

This `apt-get` command should help, "it updates the package cache and checks for broken dependencies." and might reproduce your error message:

- `sudo apt-get check`

  When I added some junk to my sources.list, it gave me this helpful info, pointing to the file & line that had the first error (after fixing run it again in case there's more errors):

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get check
  Reading package lists... Error!
  E: Type '<bd' is not known on line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
  E: The list of sources could not be read.
  E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
  ```

Or you can use GUI tools to manage them (may not work if they're corrupted with HTML now) see this link for help https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Or this link for help using command line / terminal tools https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine

Be very careful with your software sources, I'd make a backup copy of everything in `/ect/apt/sources.list` and `/ect/apt/sources.list.d/` first, just in case. Not knowing what your Ubuntu version is I'm not sure what the "defaults" should be, or whether you've added extra PPA's or other sources.

---

### Backup the sources.list files

Just copy them to a backup folder somewhere, in your home folder, or this should work:

`sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old`
`sudo cp -R /etc/apt/sources.list.d /etc/apt/sources.list.d.old`

---

### Restoring the default Ubuntu `sources.list`

- For Ubuntu, if you do this it should generate a new fresh `sources.list` file

  1. delete the old files (`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list` and `sudo rm -R /etc/apt/sources.list.d` but **BACKUP FIRST**).
  2. Then do **either** of:

     - Run the Software Sources (from the programs menu / dash, or `sudo software-properties-gtk` or `sudo software-sources`) select/check-mark some repos, pick a server and update.
     - **OR** Generate a new one at http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ using your version & country (to pick local mirrors), then copy & paste it into your new sources.list with
       `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
       or in a terminal  with
       `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

The site http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ has a LOT of optional PPA's too, looks quite useful.  [courtesy [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) ]

Comment: Sorry about tthat it says <class System Error> (E:Type'<!DOCTYPE' ia not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list) . How would I go about removing the file/sources? Sorry Im a newbie here.

Comment: to remove sources:  Open software center, move mouse to very top of screen, tap edit tab, open "software sources" at bottom of menu, open "other software" tab.  Scroll down as the newest additions appear to get added at bottom.

Comment: My compute is giving my back to back crash reports because of this. Should I back up my files?

Comment: edited answer with help on using/changing repos. Not sure why something keeps crashing, is update manager or something repeatedly trying to update the repos? Or a program installed from a non-Ubuntu-friendly repo?

Comment: It appears that it keeps trying to update the playonlinux and it keeps crashing every time. It opens for maybe 3 seconds at most then closes.

Comment: I've updated my answer, see the `apt-get check` part to find & remove the error

Comment: My Ubuntu version is 14.04. I have no idea what I am doing with terminal and I have already messed something up and I have no clue on to what my defaults should be. Is it possible to boot into a Safe Mode of some kind or should I just reinstall ubuntu unto my laptop?

Comment: If this is the only problem, then editing a few sources.list files doesn't require a reinstall. I'll edit some more info, from googling `ubuntu 14.04 default sources.list`. If anything is helpful please remember to select/check-mark the answer :-)