# Cannot install wine because of broken dependencies

Tags: wine, dependencies, repository

I'm running the latest version of ubuntu 64 bit (14.04) on a computer that is only a few weeks old. I can't install wine with the software center or the command line. I have tried every simple fix like manually adding the repository and upgrading which doesn't help at all. I have also tried different variations of the install command like apt-get install wine1.6:amd64, apt-get install wine1.6 -f, etc. I have tried installing a different version of wine also to no avail. This might look like a question with lots of duplicates but it isn't, I have looked at all the similar ones and their solutions are either non existent or non functional in my case.

I get the following error message with the software center:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is a virtual package
```

And the following error if I try using the command line:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

All the variations of the install command give me similar errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as it turns out this issue was not fixable. At least not by using any method that I found for fixing dependencies. I reinstalled ubuntu and it is now installing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Synaptic or Aptitude? Should be able to search for & install specific packages from there, and I read aptitude "tries harder" when confronted with some errors.

Did you search for the "held broken packages" solutions? Tried `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` and un-hold or remove them? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

I'd also guess your repositories are a little messed up, wine's in the standard repos (main, restricted, universe, multiverse, etc) & shouldn't need anything special. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu or the section from [this answer "Restoring the default Ubuntu sources.list"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563539/software-center-keeps-crashing/563556#563556)

Comment: I tried using aptitude and it doesn't do the job either. I can't use synaptics because it claims that in order to install wine I first have to uninstall all of my programs including ones required to keep my computer running.