# Package dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-center, java

I am trying to install java in Ubuntu but it is giving me this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install default-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jre : Depends: default-jre-headless (= 1:1.6-43ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: openjdk-6-jre (>= 6b23~pre11-1ubuntu1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to install anything from **Software Center** either

It shows me this error:

[[image: package dependencies could not be resolved]

When I go to **Software Center > Edit  > Software Sources** is disabled.

I have tried many solution but nothing works:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

[I tried this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23038484)

This the result of `apt-cache policy default-jre` and `apt-cache policy default-jre-headless`.

```
$ apt-cache policy default-jre
default-jre:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.6-43ubuntu2
  Version table:
     1:1.6-43ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages

$ apt-cache policy default-jre-headless
default-jre-headless:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.6-43ubuntu2
  Version table:
     1:1.6-43ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
```

When I tried `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` it does't show any error!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: @the_Seppi no luck!

Comment: @Xen2050 I have tried this question!

Comment: So what packages are held? And tried  un-hold / upgrade / remove them?

Comment: @Xitas: What's the output of `apt-cache policy default-jre` and `apt-cache policy default-jre-headless`?

Comment: @saiarcot895 i have update my question please check it!

Comment: @Xen2050 I have tried everything I but i had no luck so far i still don't know what the probem!

Comment: Do sudo apt-get update before installing it.

Comment: @txwikinger i have tried that. This problem was solve but updating my source.list file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thought it would have been from actually "held" packages, but maybe not, or maybe not the only problem...

I've seen similar errors before caused from using non-standard repositories (wrong version/distro, odd private or PPAs). You might want to check your repos and try to reset them to "defaults."

This *may not* solve the problem, but making a backup copy of your current repos (sources.list... files) it would be easy to check & undo later.

Here's info from another answer of mine on [**Restoring Default Ubuntu Sources**](https://askubuntu.com/a/563556/129271):

### Backup the sources.list files

Just copy them to a backup folder somewhere, this should work:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old
sudo cp -R /etc/apt/sources.list.d /etc/apt/sources.list.d.old
```

or put the copy in your home somewhere:

```
sudo cp -R /etc/apt/sources.list* /home/myuser/
```

### Restoring the default Ubuntu `sources.list`

- For Ubuntu, if you do this it should generate a new fresh `sources.list` file

  1. delete the old files (`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list` and `sudo rm -R /etc/apt/sources.list.d`  but **BACKUP FIRST**).
  2. Then do **either** of:

     - Run the Software Sources (from the programs menu / dash, or `sudo software-properties-gtk` or `sudo software-sources`) select/check-mark some repos, pick a server and update.
     - **OR** Generate a new one at http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ using your version & country (to pick local mirrors), then copy & paste it into your new sources.list with
       `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
       or in a terminal  with
       `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

The site http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ has a LOT of optional PPAs too.  [courtesy of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) ]