# Problem Installing off of Terminal

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I have this problem where I try to:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-fastboot
```

but instead of searching the internet, it tries to look on my disk drive:

```
E: Unable to locate package android-tools-fastboot
```

Comment: That's not referring to a drive, it's referring to an error. The problem is that there is no such package in the repositories your computer knows about. Google "android-tools-fastboot ubuntu repository" for help.

Comment: You're thinking that `E:` as a disk drive, but that's a Windows notation.

Answer (score 2):

It is searching the internet (via previously downloaded package lists). The package `android-tools-fastboot` is [not available for 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=android-tools-fastboot) via the official repositories. Use the [Phablet Tools PPA](https://launchpad.net/~phablet-team/+archive/ubuntu/tools) instead.

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your Software repositories? See [Ubuntu's Repo help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) &/or [this Q](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569149/cant-install-anytime-in-ubuntu/569647#569647)? The package [android-tools-fastboot](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=android-tools-fastboot) is in the `universe` FYI

Then did an `sudo apt-get update` and finally a `sudo apt-get install android-tools-fastboot`

--- Just noticed the 12.04 tag & muru's answer, it is only available for 14.04 and up... (+1 to muru :-)

Comment: I am an ABSOLUTE beginner fyi. Do you have some sort of link to show me how to edit repos?

Comment: Um, yes, the Ubuntu's Repo help link in my answer should be pretty good, it's even got some pictures `8-)` https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu