# nvidia-96 Drivers don't seem to exist?

Tags: 14.04, drivers

In the Ubuntu Software Center, the `nvidia-96` package come up when Searched, but when clicked on "**more detail**s", it brings me to a "**Not Found**"

It doesn't work through the terminal either, `apt-get` reports that the package is not found.

I need these legacy drivers for a system with an older graphics Card.

Comment: Did a `sudo apt-get update` first?

Comment: Yes, @Xen2050 I've tried everything I could think of, and it doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering why the package even shows up in the software center if it's "not Found"

Plus I still need the Drivers...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install additional drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

The Software Center may not always work 100%, try using another program like `synaptic` (GUI, easier to use), or `aptitude` (terminal, but with menus, "semi-gui", <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> opens the menu, then arrows, or mouse clicks might work), or the command line tools like:

```
apt-cache search "nvidia"
```

For me a partial output is:

```
$ apt-cache search "nvidia"
dmraid - Device-Mapper Software RAID support tool
conky-all - highly configurable system monitor (all features enabled)
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ubuntu-drivers-common - Detect and install additional Ubuntu driver packages
```

and after finding some packages (name is the first part, before the "`-`") a closer look with:

```
apt-cache show <packagename>
```

And install with

```
sudo apt-get install <packagename>
```

---

Did you change any Software Repositories? That can cause strange errors sometimes. These links might be useful about changing/resetting them:

- [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki - Repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories)
- [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki - Repositories in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)
- [Answer on Restoring Default Ubuntu Repositories (sources)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569149/cant-install-anytime-in-ubuntu/569647#569647)