# Packages are broken with unmet dependencies - cannot install fglrx

Tags: apt, package-management, ati, dpkg, fglrx

I'm new to Ubuntu and trying to survive, but, I can't figure this one out - hopefully it's easy!

Ubuntu Software Center says: New software can't be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?

When I do, it just fails.

I think it all started when I tried to install a better drive from AMD's site for my video card. Based on information from the terminal window I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and I got

```
relskhan@Ceti-Alpha-V:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for relskhan: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for relskhan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fglrx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fglrx
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 97 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/59.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 260 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 280931 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../fglrx_2%3a13.350.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fglrx (2:13.350.1-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx_2%3a13.350.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/acpi/fglrx-powermode.sh', which is also in package fglrx-core 2:14.501-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx_2%3a13.350.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am definitely at a loss and need help!

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10366408/

@Naveen

Comment: My *apt-sense* (like spidey-sense) is telling me that your sources.list files ([repos](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)) are messed up. Might want to see this answer on [Reset Default sources.list](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569149/cant-install-anytime-in-ubuntu/569647#569647)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10366408/) indicates the below packages have unmet dependencies:

- fglrx-amdcccle
- xvba-va-driver

Which means APT tried to install the above packages but failed half way, because some other required packages are not available in your system.
Therefore we need to remove the above packages before doing anything else. Run in Terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all fglrx-amdcccle xvba-va-driver
```

Then we can remove all the `fglrx` related packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
```

You can install the new fglrx:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

Comment: Still getting unmet depedencies error on apt-get install -f

Comment: I don't know how to attach a copy of what the output is

Comment: Preparing to unpack .../fglrx_2%3a13.350.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ..
Unpacking fglrx (2:13.350.1-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx_2%3a13.350.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/acpi/fglrx-powermode.sh', which is also in package fglrx-core 2:14.501-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx_2%3a13.350.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Ok I updated the answer

Comment: Please use http://paste.ubuntu.com to attach your output

Comment: I think this is what you wanted? (Still not working)

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10366408/

Comment: I updated the answer once again. See if that works :)

Comment: Cool. I explained the answer.