# Hybrid Graphics problem - Discrete graphic card doesn't work

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, hybrid-graphics

I am using a Lenovo G510 with an Intel integrated card and a Radeon R7 M265 discrete card. Ubuntu version is 14.04 trusty while the kernel is `3.13.0-46-generic`. I've spent quite a few hours trying to make Radeon to work and at this point I am close to giving up. I tried to use the proprietary fgrlx drivers but I wouldn't be able to boot, if I don't boot and I try to run amdconfig it says that no supported adapter was found and I even tried to use vgaswitcheroo without success. I just don't know what's wrong at this point and I would really like to solve this issue so that I can do some OpenGL work without resorting to switching to Windows. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I am not into ati tech but these tutorials must be good https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver  and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish Thanks but these are not something that I haven't tried.

Comment: so you did try this topic 3.2. Manually installing Catalyst 13.4, special case for Intel/AMD hybrid graphics ? Usually manually installed Catalyst did the trick as I recall.

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish I tried but the driver for my card was on a deb file of apparently `not debian format`. No installer.

Comment: If I attempt to install the deb files provided with the the generic Linux32&64bit package, I get fglrx conflicts with ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64 and the installation fails

Comment: take a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/540780/14-10-wine-and-fglrx-conflict there's a fix from David Jones. There's always a way to come it around when installing drivers not provided by Ubuntu a lot of conflicts may happen and you have to drop them or blacklist them. I faced similar issues for the first time I was installing drivers to my Nvidia but on the way you learn it. :)

Comment: simplier way is to remove `fglrx` at all, when I'm installing video drivers I remove everything that relates to video including Ubuntu native video drivers) you just have to know after that how to behave with your videocard. And it works.:)

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish what's interesting is that all questions about ocl-icd-lipencl1 are about wine while I don't have wine installed.

Comment: it's not about Wine as I said it's about `fglrx` conflicts. Like in the first answer said: try to install Wine without `fglrx` then substitute (Wine) with what you're doing. Don't get curious about Wine it's about fglrx.

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish Thanks for your help! Unfortunately no matter what I do I get errors like this one: `dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-updates_2%3a13.350.1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/acpi/fglrx-powermode.sh', which is also in package fglrx-updates-core 2:14.201-0ubuntu2.1
`

Comment: You have to purge fglrx, check this it has to solve it http://askubuntu.com/questions/588742/packages-are-broken-with-unmet-dependencies-cannot-install-fglrx

Comment: @JohnyEnglish I had already purged fglrx at that point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21656/discussion-between-veritas-and-johnnyenglish).

Answer (score 0):

Using mesa this should work, but i do recommend to upgrade to the latest ubuntu release or use [the updated oibaf drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) and probably also update the kernel using the latest [from here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/), but both mesa and the kernel have improved a lot in the last few years for the 3D support and fixed many problems

Finally [check this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593098/hybrid-graphic-card-drivers-amd%C2%AE-radeon-hd-8570-intel-hd-graphics-4000) for the direct usage of each GPU