# Codeblocks not working properly

Tags: 15.10, code-blocks

I was running Ubuntu 15.04 until yesterday and codeblocks worked fine, but when I upgraded distro to 15.10 it broke some functionalities. For example, before I used `codeblocks program.cpp > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &` for opening a program via terminal, but now it only opens the first program. For example:

`codeblocks A.cpp > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &` // codeblocks starts and A.cpp is opened
`codeblocks B.cpp > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &` // nothing happens, B.cpp is not opened
(had I written 'A.cpp B.cpp' instead of 'A.cpp' in the first line it would open both)

Moreover, on second use of 'open file' through codeblocks, it breaks and displays a white screen, and stops responding (the white screen is of the small open file screen, not the big one, but both unresponsive).[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24ppy.png)

I have tried to reinstall codeblocks multiple times, once through source code, but it didn't help. Often a problem with dependencies popped up, though.

Here's the [stdout](http://textuploader.com/516s8) and stderr of running `codeblocks C.cpp > STDOUT 2> STDERR &` and immediately closing it. It would at the end say something in the style of 'Aborted (core dumped)'. (for stderr replace in url of stdout '516s8' with '516a9')

How can I 'unbreak' codeblocks ?

Recently attempted
`codeblocks A.cpp &`
`codeblocks D.cpp &`
Running second line gives these errors textuploader . com / 50ict

Comment: Sounds like a bug in codeblocks, or they changed their mind about how multiple terminal runs will open files.  Maybe there's a new method they want you top open files with? Or if a bug, a newer or older version could work, maybe one that can work with the other installed packages, so little to no dependency problems?

Comment: I don't know, but I fiddled a bit and got a system error from trying to install codeblocks-contrib.
link to the output : http://textuploader.com/503ng
the exact terminal command was : sudo apt-get install codeblocks-contrib

Comment: I did try to install another version, but either I failed, or it is broken on 15.10 as well.

Comment: codeblocks is in the Ubuntu universe repos, so it should install properly with `apt` or the software center... are your repos changed or corrupted?  Maybe re-setting the repos might fix things, see [this answer - especially the *Backup the sources.list files* and *Restoring the default Ubuntu sources.list* sections](http://askubuntu.com/questions/563539/software-center-keeps-crashing/563556#563556) . I'd try that before something drastic like a clean re-install of 15.10 (have a backup of your home & data first) Doing a distro upgrade, like from 15.04 to 15.10, has caused problems in the past.